# Embedding html,javascript,css as resource and using in web control

Tags: c#, .net

I am using a web browser control that display html page in window form now I want to embed html and javascript files and css files as resource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Add your resource files - HTML, CSS, JS files etc. to your Visual Studio project.
- Select the file and goto Properties window for that file by pressing F4.
- Set the "Build Action" property to "Embedded Resource"
- Re-compile the application
- Use the following answer to get the embedded resource - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3314213/10458

PS: If you have a default namespace set in your project's properties, then you will have to prefix that to the file-name. For example if your file-name is `File1.html` and your default namespace is `MyCompany.MyProject` then you will have to use `GetManifestResourceStream("MyCompany.MyProject.File1.html")`.

Comment: I have css in my html and the web browser control seems to be ignoring it. More specifically I have css that will give my divs rounded corners...

Comment: If you embed a javascript file as a resource then how do you refer to it from the embedded html?

Comment: better than the microsoft documentation

Answer (score 0):

Try using [res:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767740%28VS.85,loband%29.aspx) protocol. For example

```
res://C:\path\to\exe_or_dll\project.exe/helloworld.htm
```