# HTML/CSS/JavaScript Webproject as Standalone Application

Tags: javascript, c#, html, visual-studio, geckofx

I have a very basic webproject with html,css,javascript files and also some images in the folderstructure that will be shown on the site. I use javascript functions that only work in Mozilla Firefox. My goal is to make a standalone application out of that project for windows. It will be used on several computers which all will be offline. I created a C# Project in Visual Studio Enterprise 2015.

First I copied my html folderstructure into the c# application folder and wrote some basic code to show it in the c# webbrowser. It works with all its features. Even with the released .exe file (when started from the release folder). (I used GeckoFX as webbrowser btw because it only works with the Firefox Engine)

Copying the generated .exe file somewhere else and starting it, it obviously does not work anymore, since the relative folder structure is missing. I did some reading and I implemented the html folder structure into the c# project.
I did it like that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9361642/4615422

The html file gets loaded properly into the webbrowser, but the css,javascript and everything else gets ignored.

Any ideas what I can do to solve that?

Comment: Set your paths to relative instead of absolute?

Comment: They are already relative. All of them. For example <img src="images/bla.png"></img>